# Cypress: How to handle or automate 2FA with SMS code?

Tags: cypress

When working on E2E test using Cypress, actions that require 2FA with Rolling code can be handled by using various npm packages such as jsotp but how about 2FA with SMS code? Is there a way to know what SMS code was sent to the test user's linked mobile so I can simulate the login flow in my test?

I tried searching in Google but I haven't found anything useful other than using Playwright (https://www.mailslurp.com/guides/test-sms-otp-mfa-using-playwright/).

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77149299/handling-multiple-tabs-in-cypress-is-it-possible-to-visit-a-2nd-tab-and-come-b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get an actual SMS number to use during your e2e tests. Any messages sent to this SMS number should then available to you during your tests.

We use Mailosaur for this using Cypress but you could use other frameworks or languages if you needed to.
see https://mailosaur.com/docs/sms-testing

The code is pretty simple:

```js
// Send an SMS message to your test number...

const message = await mailosaur.messages.get('SERVER_ID', {
sentTo: '1234567890' // YOUR_TEST_NUMBER
   }, {
     receivedAfter: testStart
   });
   
console.log(message.text.body); // "Your order number is 51223"
console.log(message.text.codes[0].value); // "51223"
```